# How to convert from void method to int[] method permutation method

Tags: java

I need to return value from method permutation

```
public void permute(int []a,int k ) {

if(k==a.length)

  jTextArea1.append(Arrays.toString(a)+"\n");

else
for (int i = k; i< a.length; i++) {
  int temp=a[k];
  a[k]=a[i];
  a[i]=temp;
  permute(a,k+1);
  temp=a[k];
  a[k]=a[i];
  a[i]=temp;
  }
}
```

so what I need how to convert that to this

```
public int[] permute(int []a,int k ) {
.....

}
```

for expmle  I have this code main

```html
public static void main(String[] args) {
Permutation p=new Permutation();






int a[]={1,2,3};
//p.permute(a, 0);

System.out.println((p.permute(a, 0)));

}
```

works .

but I need to do thats

```html
public int[] permute(int []a,int k ) {




return 

}
```

and give the result all permutation of a

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What is the supposed outcome? One permutation?

Comment: that return just first for exmple if I passed {1,2,3} return just 
{1,2,3]

Comment: How does this method actually works? As far as I can see, it will always return the same array as the original one, but do a lot of (useless) work...

Comment: Who tagged this as C#? It's got a jTextArea in it. I wouldn't put money on it being C#.

Comment: @ABoschman Shhhhh. The j stands for C#. :).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and I share the solation

```html
  public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> permute(int[] num) {
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
 
 //start from an empty list
 result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
 
 for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {

  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> current = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
 
  for (ArrayList<Integer> l : result) {
   
   for (int j = 0; j < l.size()+1; j++) {
    
    l.add(j, num[i]);
 
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(l);
    current.add(temp);
 
   
   
    l.remove(j);
   }
  }
 
  result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(current);
 }
 
 return result;
}
```